# How do you find factors of a number and save the factors in an array for C?

Tags: arrays, indexing, factors

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        int x, i, j=0;
        char factors[101];

        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &x);

        for(i=1;i<=x;i++)
        {
            if(x%i==0)
            {
                factors[j]=i;
                j++;
                printf("%d\t", i);
            }
        }
        getchar();
        printf("%s", factors);

    }
```

My goal was to find the factors of a number and store the factors in an array.

When I ran this code, it does find the factors but when I try printing the array, it prints characters? The factors are printed because of the i not because of the array. How do I fix this and why does it do that?

Comment: Why not make factors an integer array and count the number of factors. Then you can print it out nicely.

Comment: @Transcendental I need to store each factor to an index in an array so later on I could access each factor to perform other operations on them.

Comment: Check out my answer bellow. You can still access these factors separately. Better still, you can access them as integers and use in calculations right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use integer array instead i.e:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x, i, j=0;
    int factors[101];

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    for(i=1;i<=x;i++)
    {
        if(x%i==0)
        {
            factors[j++]=i;
            printf("%d\t", i);
        }
    }
    getchar();
    for(int k =0;k<j;++k)
    printf("%d\n",factors[k]);
}
```

There's a lot more work to do if you want to keep it a char array since factors may be greater than 10 nad one character can represent only one digit. If you know your number will have factors less than 10 then you could do : `factors[j]=i+48;` in your original code. But i do not recommend this as it is not a real solution and will work only on a small set of inputs.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! This code works as I wanted it to. thank you thank youuu!